# Area of a revolution surface proof

Tags: calculus, surfaces

I am trying to prove the following statement:

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow R$ be an integrable function.  Prove that the area of surface revolution obeys:

$$A = 2 \pi \int\limits^b_a f(x) \sqrt{1 + \bigg(\frac{df(x)}{dx}\bigg)^2}dx$$

I tried using the area of a cylinder but I couldn't get to a point where I got the integral.

Comment: Each differential area is a ring of circumference $2 \pi f(x)$ and transverse length $\sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{df(x)}{dx}\right)^2}$.

Comment: The only thing is how to get the transverse length, I can't join both ideas

Comment: draw the points  $(x,y=f(x)),(x+dx, y=f(x+dx)= f(x)+f'(x)dx=y+dy)$, the horizontal segment $dx$ the vertical $dy$ the hypotenuse which is almost the arc made by the function ..

Comment: It comes from the arc length formula,  $\mathrm ds = \sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2} \, \mathrm dx$, which can be [shown](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ArcLength.aspx) with the Pythagorean and Mean Value theorems.

Comment: It is was introduced to me as the frustum of a cone.  The area is the "slant height" times the circumference. $\sqrt {1+ f'(x)}\ dx$ is the slant height.  $2\pi f(x)$ is the circumference.

Comment: You may have a look at this answer : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1692595/72031

Answer (score 2):

Each differential area is a ring of circumference $2 \pi f(x)$ and transverse length $\sqrt{(dx)^2 + (df(x))^2} = dx \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{df(x)}{dx} \right)^2}$

[image]

[image]