# Relationship between sphere area and length of a circle.

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, spheres

I know the formula for the area of a sphere of radio $R$, $4\pi R^2$, can be derived using surface integrals, but I'm interested in how the area of a sphere of can be derived from the length of a circle of the same length. So consider a sphere of radio $R$. We can think of all the circles obtained by cutting the sphere with horizontal planes. Since the union of all these circles is the sphere and two circles do not intersect each other, it seems that the area of the sphere should be the (infinite) sum of the lengths of the circles. However, when trying to check if this works, I get the wrong result:
$$2\int_0^R 2\pi r dr = 2\pi R^2$$

What did go wrong? I know my claim 'the area of the sphere should be the (infinite) sum of the lengths of the circles' must be incorrect, but I'd like to see why.

I read about the onion proof for deriving the area of a circle from its lenght and Pappus theorem to get the are of a revolution surface from the length of the generating curve, and I thought the case of the sphere and the horizontal circles would be similar, kind of an extension of Fubini's theorem to reduce the dimension $n$ of what we want to compute and obtain it from a measure of a objects of dimension $n-1$.

Comment: You need to think about approximating the surface of the sphere by frusta of cones, not by surfaces of cylinders. You are using a leg of a right triangle where you need its hypotenuse.

Comment: @TedShifrin So the problem with my approach is that it does not include information about the radii of the different curves evolve? I thought more about it and just realize that all cones with the same base are the disjoint union of circles with radii from 0 to the radius of the base. And obviously their areas are different: they depend of the height, which determines how the radii evolve from bottom to top.

Comment: Look in a standard calculus book at how you compute arclength and area of a surface of revolution using single integrals.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. I did, and I understand now.

Comment: [Possibly of interest](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691147/why-is-surface-area-not-simply-2-pi-int-ab-y-dx-instead-of-2-pi-in)

Comment: Describe r in terms of R.